# Vim: Issue with visual mode commands

Tags: vim

I'm simply trying perform some commands on text that is selected in visual mode. 
If I select some text & then press y (for yank) or d (for delete), it yanks or deletes the selected text  
However I need to be able to do this from the command line (because I'm writing a function that I'm going to remap to one of my keys).  
However when I enter the command line from visual mode `'<,'>` is there by default, so I just try to append y or d to the end of it leaving me with `:'<,'>d`  
The problem with this however is that it deletes the whole line that the visual selection is in. I only want to delete the selection I made within the line.  
 
I've tried looking at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection but nothing I try seems to work.  
I'm sure it must be something simple but I just don't know what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your goal? I am starting to think this may be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

All Vim native ex commands work on lines. I guess you can buck this trend. However you seem to be wanting to create a command simply so you can map it some key(s). You probably just want to call the function directly or creating a `<Plug>` or `<SID>` mapping instead.

#### Calling a function directly

```
xnoremap * :<c-u>call YourFunctionGoesHere<cr>
```

The secret sauce using `:<c-u>call` here. You probably want to use `:normal! gv` inside your function.

#### Using `<Plug>`

Here is a quick-n-dirty visual start example showing:

```
function! s:vstar()
  let reg = @@
  normal! gvy
  let @/ = '\V' . substitute(escape(@@, '\'))
  let @@ = reg
endfunction

xnoremap <Plug>(vstar) :<c-u>call <SID>vstar()<cr>/<c-r>/<cr><cr>
```

This show how to create the `<Plug>` map which shows how to call a function which is the same as calling the function directly example. The use of `<SID>`/`s:` makes sure the function is "namespace'd" to the current script.

Now you can just map `*` to your `<Plug>` mapping like in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
xmap * <Plug>(vstar)
```

This is how Vim Plugin's create their mappings. A good starting place for learning Vim plugins is `:h write-plugin` and looking at some very popular vim plugins. I suggest you look at Tim Pope's or Ingo Karkat's plugins as both are very prolific authors.

For more help see:

```
:h <Plug>
:h <SID>
:h using-<Plug>
:h write-plugin
:h c_ctrl-u
:h :norm
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still didn't work for me. I probably just don't get it. Anyway I ended up just assigning markers & deleting between the 2 of them. This avoided me having to enter visual mode at all.